# Azure Active Directory Authentication with and Existing App which is using Identity framework for user authentication. Using ADAL or Web Api

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-authentication

I have an application made in dotnet mvc made in C# which is using Asp Identity framework for user authentication and authorization.

I need to integrate a method which can authenticate user first agaist Azure actice directory then login using Identity framework.

I know how to Authenticate user against Azure active Directory by selecting user authentication type school or organization and then registring your app on Azure app registration.

It would automatically redirect you to login using your domain username and password, then authenticate against Azure Active directory. But that is for new application.

The problem here is I can not use the default method of automatically generating code for user authenticating against Azure Active Directory because at same time either you can use Identity framework or Azure AD authentication.

Is is possible to do by passing email and passowrd to an api or any better way of doing this. Any help would be much appreciated. Or you can provde me some sample code that will be icing on the cake. Thank you

or Microsoft Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) can help me? Kindly give me a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to authenticate to your app with two different scenarios.It can achieve easily by using Azure AD B2C. Hope this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c?view=aspnetcore-3.1) will help you.

Also, if you want to use ADAL then it is recommended to use MSAL instead  since Starting June 30th, 2020, we will no longer add new features to ADAL. We'll continue adding critical security fixes to ADAL until June 30th, 2022. Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration).